# Google Places API Not Returning Results

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

I'm working with the Places API and having difficulty getting responses.

Here is a sample query using the name Google

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Google&inputtype=textquery&fields=photos,formatted_address,name,rating,opening_hours,geometry&key=key

returns :

```
{
    candidates: [ ],
    status: "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

However If I do:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Museum%20of%20Contemporary%20Art%20Australia&inputtype=textquery&fields=photos,formatted_address,name,rating,opening_hours,geometry&key=key

I get results

Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I just enabled my billing because it said my account was over limit due to no billing.

Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're going to like my answer but I'm going to put it up anyway.

The first link does nothing more than search for **Google** and clearly (and also without knowing the specifics), that search is far too broad for the engine to come up with an appropriate list of places.

If you search for "**Google Australia**", "**Google Asia**" or "**Google America**" then you will get an answer so clearly it's looking for a more specific search text to work with.

You can see yourself that when you specify **Museum of Contemporary Art, Australia** you get an answer but searching for just **Museum** yields no results because again, it's too broad.  However, searching for **Museum Melbourne** yields 2 results.

Now, having said all of that, you can search for just **Google** but if you want it to return results, you'll need to provide some location information.  See the `locationbias` parameter in the doco for how to do that.

The example below worked using my IP Address ...

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Google&inputtype=textquery&fields=photos,formatted_address,name,rating,opening_hours,geometry&locationbias=ipbias&key=YOUR_KEY

[image: Test Results]

I noticed that using the circle radius selects the closest place (I tested with **Hospital**) to the edge of the radius, not all places within the radius.

This is straight from the doco ...

[image: Documentation]

Another way to search for things is via the **NearBySearch** method rather than the text search, especially if you're looking for specific types of business and also within a specific radius, not just the closest to the edge of the radius.

This example ...

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-37.814,144.96332&radius=1500&type=hospital&key=YOUR_KEY

... returns all "hospitals" (loose term) within a 1500m radius of the lat long (which in this case is Melbourne).  You can also add keywords into the search if you need to.  This may actually be a better approach for what you're wanting but you can make that decision yourself.

This example ...

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-37.814,144.96332&radius=50000&keyword=google&key=YOUR_KEY

... returns all places that have a reference to the word **Google** within a 50km radius of Melbourne.  To narrow down the results, add a `type` filter to only select those types of establishments you want, just like the hospital example.

See this link for all of the supported types ...

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types

Not sure if it's what you're after but I hope it helps.